# DCC as a model of dynamic conditional autocorrelation?

Tags: autocorrelation, change-point

Is it a good idea to use DCC to estimate dynamic conditional autocorrelation? So far I was using the indirect method for detecting changes in autocorrelation - in R strucchange package by Score-CUSUM and Score-MOSUM on a plot with the "functional = max" parameter which gives division into a coefficient of regression (in this case AR) and variance parts. If variance doesn't change, but coefficients change significantly, it means that autocorrelation really changes in time. But as I said, this is indirect method, and question concerns differences in effects of both methods. I'm leaving aside the fact that DCC is special for ARCH class, in contrast to CUSUM / MOSUM.

I know there are other methods, like VARMA. It is probably the next thing I will check. However, I must understand the difference between assumptions which can give different results.

Comment: How do you define dynamic conditional autocorrelation? Is there a paper/book/lecture note that you are following?

Comment: Same as Dynamic Conditional Correlation, such that the second variable is the first lagged variable. For this purpose I use 'rmgarch' package which refers to: Engle, R.F. and Sheppard, K. 2001, "Theoretical and empirical properties of dynamic c.onditional
correlation multivariate GARCH".

Comment: If they are the same, why are you using a different name?

Comment: Because the GARCH model takes into account the variance autocorrelations, and this fact alone is probably why I'm not sure whether the lagged variable can be treated as an ordinary dependent/independent variable. In addition, there are potential long-run autocorrelations, because DCC only examines the short-run.

Comment: I am still a little confused by your explanation. Could you perhaps write down some model equations to show what kind of process you have in mind? Also, the DCC equation has three elements: a constant to set the level, a "squared" error for the short-term effect and an autoregressive term for the long-term effect. So it does cover the long-term effect.

Comment: DCC is the structure of two equations: (1)
Q_t = (1 - alpha - beta) * Q_bar + alpha * nu_{t-1} * nu_{t-1}’ + beta * Q_{t-1}
where: Q_t is the estimated conditional covariance matrix at time t.
Q_bar is the unconditional covariance matrix of the standardized residuals.
nu_{t-1} is the vector of standardized residuals from the first step at time t-1.
alpha and beta are parameters to be estimated so that alpha + beta < 1 for stationarity.
(2)
R_t = diag(Q_t)^{-1} * Q_t * diag(Q_t)^{-1}
where R_t is the time-varying conditional correlation matrix.
diag(Q_t) is a diagonal matrix

Comment: Comparing to simple Peason correlation, dynamic will be analogous: ρ_ijt = q_ijt / sqrt(q_iit * q_jjt)

where:

q_ijt is the (i, j) element of the conditional covariance matrix Q_t.
q_iit and q_jjt are the i-th and j-th diagonal elements of Q_t, respectively.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I did not mean to ask what DCC is because I can look this up myself. I am asking what you mean by *dynamic conditional autocorrelation* (DCAC). Could it be something like VAR+DCCGARCH or VARMA+DCCGARCH? Or would a constant+DCCGARCH do (in which case I do not see a reason to use *auto* and thus we have DCC, not DCAC)?

Comment: Let's start with the rmgarch package, and the function DCCtest(Data), garchOrder = c(1,1)). In Data I put my sample and its lagged version. DCCtest itself should work fine because I only set GARCH orders, not AR.This test does not take into account (variation) of the autoregression. The matter may be more complicated when fitting the model, i.e. with dccfit. There you can create ARMA-GARCH and here I have more doubts, as the correlation variability is examined on the basis of values purified from the average correlation (in the form of ARMA).